# Accessing an object's value that has the same name as a php special name function

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, object, woocommerce

I have an array of objects

```
       [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [term_id] => 21
                        [name] => House
                        [slug] => house
                        [term_group] => 0
                        [term_taxonomy_id] => 21
                        [taxonomy] => product_cat
                        [description] => 
                        [parent] => 16
                        [count] => 2
                        [filter] => raw
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [term_id] => 12
                        [name] => stone
                        [slug] => stone
                        [term_group] => 0
                        [term_taxonomy_id] => 12
                        [taxonomy] => product_cat
                        [description] => 
                        [parent] => 8
                        [count] => 1
                        [filter] => raw
                    )

            )
```

and I need to check the `[parent]` value.
But as parent refers to http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php

Using something like:

```
foreach ($array_entry as $object) {
 if ($object->parent === $something) {
     ....
   } else {
     ....
   }
}
```

doesn't work.
How can I access the parent value?
I have tried `'parent'` which still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($array_entry as $object) {
    var_dump( $object->{'parent'} );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  foreach($array_entry as $key => $object){
    print_r($object->parent);
  }
```